# Windows 2008 Firewall - How do I restrict HTTP inbound to specific IP?

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-server-2008-r2

My goal is to restrict all HTTP inbound requests to a specific IP addresses. I thought it would be a simple process - but I am not getting the result desired

I have modified a predefined rule called  WWW (HTTP Traffic-In) - so that it "Block" incoming connection (and made sure the this inbound rule's Scope applies to the currently active Profile)

I did not at this stage - specify allowable IPs - as I want to see if the rule would block ALL  http traffic inbound.

In the Private Profile (which is the active profile) - i have these settings:
    - Firewall state: On
    - Inbound connections: Allow
    - Outbound connections: Block

Windows Firewall Overview Page shows:
    - Private Profile is Active
    - Inbound connections that do not match a rule are allowed
    - Outbound connections that do not match a rule are blocked

However, the firewall rule still allowed HTTP traffic inward and my Windows 2008 server still responded with a test page

I know it should be a simple task setting up a firewall rule - but perhaps I missing something  ??

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with TWO rules and not just one. Since, as far as I know, the rules list is read from the top (the first rule in the list) to the end and the order of rules in the list is important.

Ref.: [TechNet: Order of Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Rules Evaluation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755191%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

The *first rule* you have to create must *allow* all IP addresses you want to authorized from remote ports 80.

The *second rule* must *block* all other incoming TCP packets from remote port 80 (Http).

The first rules will inspect incoming TCP packets: **if** they are from from remote ports 80 in TCP **AND** corresponding to the IP addresses you want to allow. they will be allowed. The packet MUST match all specification of that rule to be allowed. **If not** the *next rule* will check the incoming packets.

**If** the incoming TCP packets do not match all criteria of the first rule **then** the second rule will check if TCP packets are from remote ports 80 to block all of them *but not* the others TCP packets (on remote ports different than 80) since you want to block HTTP not in your IP address list and not all other TCP packets...

Comment: @harrymc: Read the question. The asker (for no clear reason) decided to swap the default rules for inbound and outbound: inbound is now allow-by-default (and outbound is block-by-default, which is reasonable on a server but not the default out of the box).